# How to add data of multiple files in different cell in excel?

Tags: excel

For example, Lets say I have 5 text files.

**file name :** File1.txt 
**data :** vmkfmoemfvkmdfv

**file name :** File2.txt 
**data :** ppvlvlvl

**file name :** File3.txt 
**data :** wwwererer

**file name :** File4.txt 
**data :** mmki

**file name :** File5.txt 
**data :** qwerr

Now what I want is to add each file's data into separate cells of a column.

What I did previously was- 
Opened File1.txt,
Copied all data inside it,
Selected a cell,
Pasted it in the cell.

Is there any automatic way to do that ??

Please help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to do this. If you are not prepared to make your own little program. But that's a lot more work then what you described.

Answer (score 0):

Give this tiny macro a try:

```
Sub basement()
    For i = 1 To 5
        Close #1
        Open "C:\TestFolder\File" & i & ".txt" For Input As #1
        Line Input #1, TextLine
        Cells(i, "A").Value = TextLine
        Close #1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Adjust this to use your own folder name(s)